# Implicit operator?

Tags: c#, .net, casting, operator-overloading, implicit

I need some help. I am creating a SelectItem class like this:

```
public class SelectItem<T> where T : class
{
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
    public T Item { get; set; }
}
```

I would like the following code to be valid

```
SelectItem<String> obj = new SelectItem<String> { Item = "Value" };

obj.IsChecked = true;

String objValue = obj;
```

Instead of having to do this:

```
String objValue = obj.Item;
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
public static implicit operator T(SelectItem<T> obj) {
    return obj.Item;
}
```

Comment: That was fast and easy. Thanks